# Why is Nakuru Narumi so dark skinned?

Tags: mayo-chiki

[image: enter link description here]

As we can see [Nakuru Narumi](http://myanimelist.net/character/41379/Nakuru_Narumi) has dark skin compared to other characters. So why she has dark skin tone ?

Answer (score 4):

She actually does not have dark skin tone. It is fashion called [Ganguro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganguro).

As MAL Describe her character as:

> The cat-eared [ganguro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganguro) student that is spying Konoe and Kinjirō.

Below is the defination of ganguro as described by Wikipedia.

> Ganguro (ガングロ?) is an alternative fashion trend among young Japanese women that started in the mid-1990s, distinguished by a dark tan and contrasting make-up liberally applied by fashionistas.

Comment: Did she or anyone ever mention that she's a Ganguro girls?

Comment: @OshinoShinobu it is already mention in MAL's introduction so i did not added in answer. here it is.